# NSPanel parent window floats on top of full-screened NSView

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsview, qtkit

I have an NS panel that is the child of an NS Window; the panel is set to floating window level. The parent window has an NSView that is in full screen mode, so the NSPanel, is floating on top of the full screened NSView. Anytime I click the panel, it brings the parent window into floating mode as well, such that it renders on top of the movie. Is there any way for me to prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you enter fullscreen mode, why don't you just remove the panel as a child window? It should still be displayed and function, but then it won't bring the other window forward. Then when you exit fullscreen mode, add it back as a child window.